# Better approach for storing, retrieving, saving and loading data in a TListBox?

Tags: delphi, listbox, delphi-10.4-sydney

In a Delphi 10.4.2 win-32 VCL Application in Windows 10, I use a simple `TListBox` to store records in ListBox items. When the user clicks an item then the data of the associated record are retrieved:

```
type
  PResizeSettingsRec = ^TResizeSettingsRec;
  TResizeSettingsRec = record
    TopValue:    Integer;
    LeftValue:   Integer;
    RightValue:  Integer;
    BottomValue: Integer;
    Color:       TColor;
    Opacity:     Integer;
  end;

procedure TformMain.btnAddCurrentSettingsClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  P: PResizeSettingsRec;
begin
  New(P);
  P.TopValue    := 5;
  P.LeftValue   := 5;
  P.RightValue  := 5;
  P.BottomValue := 5;
  P.Color       := clRed;
  P.Opacity     := 255;
  listboxMultiResize.AddItem('Step 1', TObject(P));

  New(P);
  P.TopValue    := 9;
  P.LeftValue   := 9;
  P.RightValue  := 9;
  P.BottomValue := 9;
  P.Color       := clBlue;
  P.Opacity     := 127;
  listboxMultiResize.AddItem('Step 2', TObject(P));
end;

procedure TformMain.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  for var i := 0 to listboxMultiResize.Items.Count - 1 do
    Dispose(PResizeSettingsRec(listboxMultiResize.Items.Objects[i]));
end;

procedure TformMain.listboxMultiResizeClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  P: PResizeSettingsRec;
begin
  if listboxMultiResize.ItemIndex < 0 then EXIT;
  P := PResizeSettingsRec(listboxMultiResize.Items.Objects[listboxMultiResize.ItemIndex]);
  CodeSite.Send('TformMain.listboxMultiResizeClick: P.TopValue', P.TopValue);
  CodeSite.Send('TformMain.listboxMultiResizeClick: P.LeftValue', P.LeftValue);
  CodeSite.Send('TformMain.listboxMultiResizeClick: P.RightValue', P.RightValue);
  CodeSite.Send('TformMain.listboxMultiResizeClick: P.BottomValue', P.BottomValue);
  CodeSite.Send('TformMain.listboxMultiResizeClick: ColorToString(P.Color)', ColorToString(P.Color));
  CodeSite.Send('TformMain.listboxMultiResizeClick: P.Opacity', P.Opacity);
end;
```

This approach is deliberately simple to make it stable and foolproof. Or is there a better and more modern and thus easier way to achieve this?

Is there an easy way to store the ListBox items together with their data to a file and later reload them from the file? (Currently, I use an INI file).

**EDIT:** Following Andreas' advice I now use this code:

```
type
  TResizeSettings = class
    TopValue:    Integer;
    LeftValue:   Integer;
    RightValue:  Integer;
    BottomValue: Integer;
    Color:       TColor;
    Opacity:     Integer;
  end;

procedure TformMain.btnAddCurrentSettingsClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ThisResizeSettings: TResizeSettings;
begin
  ThisResizeSettings := TResizeSettings.Create;
  try
    ThisResizeSettings.TopValue    := 5;
    ThisResizeSettings.LeftValue   := 5;
    ThisResizeSettings.RightValue  := 5;
    ThisResizeSettings.BottomValue := 5;
    ThisResizeSettings.Color       := clRed;
    ThisResizeSettings.Opacity     := 255;
    listboxMultiResize.AddItem('Step 1', ThisResizeSettings);
  finally
    ThisResizeSettings.Free;
  end;

  ThisResizeSettings := TResizeSettings.Create;
  try
    ThisResizeSettings.TopValue    := 9;
    ThisResizeSettings.LeftValue   := 9;
    ThisResizeSettings.RightValue  := 9;
    ThisResizeSettings.BottomValue := 9;
    ThisResizeSettings.Color       := clBlue;
    ThisResizeSettings.Opacity     := 127;
    listboxMultiResize.AddItem('Step 2', ThisResizeSettings);
  finally
    ThisResizeSettings.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TformMain.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  for var i := 0 to listboxMultiResize.Items.Count - 1 do
  begin
    TResizeSettings(listboxMultiResize.Items.Objects[i]).Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TformMain.listboxMultiResizeClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ThisResizeSettings: TResizeSettings;
begin
  if listboxMultiResize.ItemIndex < 0 then EXIT;
  ThisResizeSettings := TResizeSettings(listboxMultiResize.Items.Objects[listboxMultiResize.ItemIndex]);
  CodeSite.Send('TformMain.listboxMultiResizeClick: TopValue', ThisResizeSettings.TopValue);
  CodeSite.Send('TformMain.listboxMultiResizeClick: LeftValue', ThisResizeSettings.LeftValue);
  CodeSite.Send('TformMain.listboxMultiResizeClick: RightValue', ThisResizeSettings.RightValue);
  CodeSite.Send('TformMain.listboxMultiResizeClick: BottomValue', ThisResizeSettings.BottomValue);
  CodeSite.Send('TformMain.listboxMultiResizeClick: ColorToString(P.Color)', ColorToString(ThisResizeSettings.Color));
  CodeSite.Send('TformMain.listboxMultiResizeClick: Opacity', ThisResizeSettings.Opacity);
end;
```

However, I get random results when clicking on a Listbox item!

**EDIT2:** After Andreas' answer I now do not free anymore the created objects:

```
procedure TformMain.btnAddCurrentSettingsClick(Sender: TObject);
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68702539/better-approach-for-storing-retrieving-saving-and-loading-data-in-a-tlistbox
var
  ThisResizeSettings: TResizeSettings;
begin
  ThisResizeSettings := TResizeSettings.Create;  
    ThisResizeSettings.TopValue    := 5;
    ThisResizeSettings.LeftValue   := 5;
    ThisResizeSettings.RightValue  := 5;
    ThisResizeSettings.BottomValue := 5;
    ThisResizeSettings.Color       := clRed;
    ThisResizeSettings.Opacity     := 255;
    listboxMultiResize.AddItem('Step 1', ThisResizeSettings);   

  ThisResizeSettings := TResizeSettings.Create;  
    ThisResizeSettings.TopValue    := 9;
    ThisResizeSettings.LeftValue   := 9;
    ThisResizeSettings.RightValue  := 9;
    ThisResizeSettings.BottomValue := 9;
    ThisResizeSettings.Color       := clBlue;
    ThisResizeSettings.Opacity     := 127;
    listboxMultiResize.AddItem('Step 2', ThisResizeSettings);  
end;
```

I have also changed the freeing of the ListBox objects in `FormDestroy`:

```
procedure TformMain.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68702539/better-approach-for-storing-retrieving-saving-and-loading-data-in-a-tlistbox
  for var i := listboxMultiResize.Items.Count - 1 downto 0 do
  begin
    listboxMultiResize.Items.Objects[i].Free;
    listboxMultiResize.Items.Objects[i] := nil;
  end;
```

Now it seems to work. Thank you, Andreas!

Comment: Instead of records, use objects. Then the ugly `TObject` cast isn't needed, because you are actually providing an object! That's how it is (mainly) supposed to be used.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Do you mean, I should declare a class with setters and getters instead of a record? Isn't a record more simple to handle? Doesn't a class add more unnecessary complexity?

Comment: A class doesn't need to have getters and setters. Instead of `type TTest = record A, B: Integer; c: string; end;` just do `type TTest = class A, B: Integer; c: string; end;`. By default, `A` and `B` and `c` will be public. No need for private fields and public properties with getters and setters if you don't need them. Yes, records are value types while objects are reference types (and you need to create and free them), but in your case, it is more convenient with reference types. Besides, you are already doing allocation and freeing, albeit in an ancient way!

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I followed your advice to use a class instead of a record. But when I click on an item in the ListBox, I get mostly random values with this code: `ThisResizeSettings := TResizeSettings(listboxMultiResize.Items.Objects[listboxMultiResize.ItemIndex]);` `CodeSite.Send('TformMain.listboxMultiResizeClick: TopValue', ThisResizeSettings.TopValue);`

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong. A start is to not use unsafe casts, but safe `as` casts.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I have posted the changed code in the Q. What is wrong with that code?

Comment: Your new code is wrong. Remember that `ThisResizeSettings := TResizeSettings.Create` first creates a new `TResizeSettings` object on the heap and then stores the address to this object in the `ThisResizeSettings` local variable. Then `listboxMultiResize.AddItem('Step 1', ThisResizeSettings);` adds a new list box item with text `Step 1` and this address. But then `ThisResizeSettings.Free` destroys the heap object, so now the list box's address is a dangling pointer, that is, a pointer that points to garbage!

Comment: (gargabe = unused memory, which may become used by some other things in the future, in which case you might cause memory corruption by pretending that this is still your ex-`TResizeSettings` object)

Comment: The object you create must live for as long as there are >= 1 references to it, including the list box's reference.

Comment: So you say I should not use `ThisResizeSettings.Free` when adding an item to the ListBox? I thought that when adding a ListBox item then this item gets a copy of the created object.

Comment: No. That's like (1) building a new home to your old parents, (2) giving them the address and telling them they may go to the new house any time, and then (3) immediately demolishing the house (without telling anyone about it!) before they have a chance to even see it a first time! (10) When they go to the address a month later, they don't know that this area is now used by the CIA, and the CIA staff gets very angry with them when they enter the area.

Comment: "I thought that when adding a ListBox item then this item gets a copy of the created object. " No. The number 1 important thing to remember: In Delphi, object variables are only pointers (64-bit integers) = addresses to the object's position in your computer's RAM ("the heap"). Very important: `Frog  := TFrog.Create` (1) allocates memory on the heap for a new `TFrog` object and (2) runs the `TFrog.Create` constructor on this pointer. (3) Then the address to this object (a 64-bit integer, a pointer) is saved in the `Frog` variable. Think of `Frog` as an address, which points to a particular ...

Comment: ... area of your computer's memory. If you do `Frog2 := Frog`, then both `Frog` and `Frog2` point to the same place (for instance, `Frog = Frog2 = 45012112`). If you destroy this `TFrog` object on the heap (e.g., by doing `Frog.Free` or `Frog2.Free` or something else), you must make sure that you after this realise that `Frog` and `Frog2` now are *dangling pointers*, that is, pointers that point to something you no longer owns or knows what it is. You must never use these pointers any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of records, use objects. Then the ugly `TObject` cast won't be needed, because you are actually providing an object! That's how it is (mainly) supposed to be used.

Remember: A class doesn't need to have getters and setters and by default a `TObject`-based class has member visibility `public`. No need for private fields and public properties with getters and setters if you don't need them. Also, records are value types while objects are reference types (and you need to create and free them), but in your case, it is more convenient with reference types. Besides, you are already doing allocation and freeing, albeit in an ancient way!

Here's a simple example:

```pascal
type
  TPerson = class
    Name: string;
    Age: Integer;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    lbPersons: TListBox;
    eName: TEdit;
    lblName: TLabel;
    eAge: TEdit;
    lblAge: TLabel;
    btnAddUpd: TButton;
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnAddUpdClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure lbPersonsClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.btnAddUpdClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  var idx := lbPersons.Items.IndexOf(eName.Text);
  var Person: TPerson;
  if idx <> -1 then
    Person := lbPersons.Items.Objects[idx] as TPerson
  else
    Person := TPerson.Create;
  Person.Name := eName.Text;
  Person.Age := StrToInt(eAge.Text);
  if idx = -1 then
    lbPersons.Items.AddObject(Person.Name, Person);
  if eName.CanFocus then
    eName.SetFocus;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  for var i := lbPersons.Items.Count - 1 downto 0 do
  begin
    lbPersons.Items.Objects[i].Free;
    lbPersons.Items.Objects[i] := nil;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.lbPersonsClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if lbPersons.ItemIndex = -1 then
  begin
    eName.Text := '';
    eAge.Text := '';
  end
  else
  begin
    var Person := lbPersons.Items.Objects[lbPersons.ItemIndex] as TPerson;
    eName.Text := Person.Name;
    eAge.Text := Person.Age.ToString;
  end;
end;
```

[image: Screenshot of test app.]

Comment: Isn't the default visibility published!?

Comment: @DelphiCoder: No, it is `public` unless the `{$M+}` directive has been used before the class declaration or the ancestor class has `published` members by default. So descendants of `TPersistent`, which includes all components (and thus all controls) have `published` as the default visibility. But `TObject` doesn't have this state, so my statement "a `TObject`-based class has member visibility public" is correct. See http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Classes_and_Objects_(Delphi)#Visibility_of_Class_Members.